# Trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express, SQL Server 2012 Mgmt Studio

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have been trying to download and install either SQL Server 2012 Express or SQL Server 2012 Management Studio so I can access my remote SQL Server 2012 tables in my Dot Net Nuke website. I am using Windows 7 OS, X86.  I have installed and verified that ALL of the following versions of the Dot Net Framework are

installed and verified:

- .NET Framework 2.0
- .NET Framework 3.5
- .NET Framework 4.0
- .NET Framework 4.5
- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- .NET Framework 4.5.2

Each and every time I attempt to install either SQL Server 2012 Express or SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, I get an error message that

> You must install either .NET Framework 2.0 or .NET Framework 4.0 to install SQL Server Express 2012

I have done this many times, I have installed and uninstalled all of these, trying different orders and different sequences starting with 2.0 by itself, then adding the others. Same error. I have looked online and I can see that many others have had similar problems, sometimes a registry hack was suggested. However, I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion that works.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: There is nothing called DNN Framework. Make sure you type everything in the correct way.

Comment: Hi, forgive me, but don't you think this question more suited in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: How did you “verified” that .NET Framework 2.0 and 4.0 are installed?

Comment: with the windows verification tool I downloaded